# Web radio buttons where you can switch all off

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, radio-button

I want to have 3 radio type buttons on my web page. If I click on one button it switches on and the other 2 in the group switch off. So far so normal. However if I click the currently 'on' button I want it to toggle to 'off'. I.e. be able to have all buttons in the group switched off.

I've had a look at the jQuery UI button, but I cant figure out how to implement this. Is this possible? Or is there some other javascript library that offers this feature?

Code example of normal jQuery radio buttons ...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#radio").buttonset();
  });

</script>
</head>
<body style="font-size:62.5%;">

<div id="radio">
    <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radio" /><label for="radio1">Choice 1</label>
    <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radio" checked="checked" /><label for="radio2">Choice 2</label>
    <input type="radio" id="radio3" name="radio" /><label for="radio3">Choice 3</label>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is your ultimate goal using the jQuery UI button set or to just have the functionality you described? You mentioned two issues in this question: turning off all the radio buttons as wells as using the jQuery UI button set.

Comment: @Zero21xxx Ideally I'd use the jQuery UI as I'm using this already (easier to use the UI theme throught). But if jQuery-UI-Button doesnt support it, then I need to look for some other way

Comment: Can you post the HTML for the radio buttons and some JavaScript?

Comment: As far as the spec is concerned, radio buttons should *never* have an "all off" state - http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#radio - so tools to help you enable this will always be a little washy

Comment: (this is different in HTML5, just for reference - http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/number-state.html#radio-button-state)

Comment: @Zero21xxx - code posted. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have done it this way:

```
$(window).ready(function() {

    var currentRadio = new Array();
    $('input:radio').bind('click', function() {
        var name = $(this).attr('name');
        if(name in currentRadio && currentRadio[name] === $(this)[0]) {
            $(this).removeAttr('checked');
            currentRadio[name] = false;
        } else {
            currentRadio[name] = $(this)[0];
        }
    });

});
```

This is universal solution for several groups of radio buttons (grouping by name).

Here it is in action: http://jsfiddle.net/LkBYc/

Answer (score 2):

What you want is, as you know, not how radio buttons work. And it is usually not such a good idea to subvert the usual behavior of any UI element. However, you could have a button labeled, say, "clear all" with an onclick handler that would clear all of the radio buttons. That's a good idea, I think: it's always a pain, imo, to have to select a second radio button to clear the checked state of the first. Of coure, you don't need jquery to do this.

To repeat, though: I wouldn't assign one of the radio-button array to act on others as you describe.

Comment: I deleted my answer because I thought about just overriding the browser's default behavior in an `onClick` event, but @Pete Wilson is correct because radio buttons are not what you want in this scenario - bad user experience as he pointed out.

Comment: @Gareth, Pete Wilson Thanks. However the functionality I want (modified radio button behaviour) needn't be implemented with the HTML radio form input. For example it could be done using checkboxes where you have customised javascript click event handlers to control what buttons are on/off - bit complicated though. So was hoping this had been done before.

Comment: @spidey -- yes, it seems checkboxes are more like what you want, to accord with usual UI practice. This has been done many, many times before so it's very usual. Though a checkbox is not supposed to provoke an action, so it's a little bit out of spec. Really not complicated as you'll see when you code it up.